# Watir gem w/ phantomjs not following oauth redirect

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, sinatra, omniauth, watir

I'm using the watir gem to login to salesforce using the omniauth-salesforce gem in a Sinatra app.  While using a normal browser, it follows the 303 redirect just fine.  However, the Watir::Browser instance of phantomjs does not.

```
  post '/authenticate/:provider' do
    case params[:provider].downcase
    when 'salesforce'
      auth_params = {
        :display => 'page',
        :immediate => 'false',
        :scope => 'full',
      }
      auth_params = URI.escape(auth_params.collect{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&'))
      redirect "/auth/salesforce?#{auth_params}"
    when 'box'
      oauth_url = Boxr::oauth_url(
        URI.encode_www_form_component(CredService.creds.box.utility_app.token),
        client_id: CredService.creds.box.utility_app.client_id
      )
      redirect oauth_url
    when 'sandbox'
      auth_params = {
        display:     'page',
        immediate:   'false',
        scope:       'full',
      }
      auth_params = URI.escape(auth_params.collect{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&'))
      redirect "/auth/salesforcesandbox?#{auth_params}"
    end
  end
```

When I authenticate via box usig `Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)`, I have no issues navigating to a login page and putting in credentials.  I believe it's because the redirect path is direct to app.box.com, whereas the omniauth redirect is first internal (`/auth/salesforce?#{auth_params}`) then it redirects again to the salesforce domain.

Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated.  I've used `binding.pry` w/ byebug and traversed the sinatra/rack code path, but I can't descern what is going on.

[here is a link](https://github.com/richardvanhook/omniauth-salesforce-example) to the omniauth-salesforce login example page

Comment: What version of phantomjs are you using? 1.9 had a lot of problems with redirects that were fixed in 2.0.